# onDispose callback not called when app is killed

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The [`onDispose`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#onDispose(kotlin.Function0)) callback isn't called when i close my app or when its process is killed. Is this intended behavior? Is there a different callback for this event? Can I make my own, by somehow passing `MainActivity`s `onStop` callback down to a composable?

The reason I need this sort of callback is because I want to save some data, that the user entered, to the database when the user leaves the screen or on process death. I learned that `SavedStateHandle` is made for this use case, but only for small amounts of data - I want to save complex, non-parcelable data and I don't want the code overhead that `SavedStateHandle` seems to have.

My current workaround is to save to the database on every change, which isn't hard since my code is reactive using coroutine `StateFlow`. I fear that this has performance implications, but maybe I'm wrong and this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killed as in force stopped/swipped from recents? If yes, then this is expected behavior, composer is disposed when `viewLifecycle` is in `ON_DESTROY` state.

From the source:

```kotlin
 override fun onStateChanged(source: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) {
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) {
            dispose()
        } else if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE) {
            if (!disposed) {
                setContent(lastContent)
            }
        }
    }
```

If `ON_DESTROY` is not dispatched, the composer will not dispose. `ProcessLifecycle` will not be helpful either.

`onDestroy` is no reliable in such case, you should await for either `onStop` or `onPause`, `onDispose` should be used to dispose any operations/resources that are related to the view.

Comment: When you say "you should await for either onStop or onPause", do you mean I should wait until these callbacks are implemented in jetpack compose? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: I meant implementing your own `LifecycleObserver`.

Comment: If you're implementing your own `LifecycleObserver` why not use the `onDestroy` from there ?