# Jetpack compose onExit event

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In a simple example, how to access the Exit event of our app, without using ViewModel or Hilt, etc.?

For example, to display a simple Toast message, while we exit the app.

The following code, when we press the **back button** to exit, works properly, and displays the toast:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        var ctx = applicationContext
        setContent {
            checkExit(ctx)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun checkExit(ctx: Context) {
    DisposableEffect(""){
        onDispose {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "onExit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

But if we minimize the app and then exit by swiping up the screen in the background, this toast will no longer be displayed

[image]

`**Working Code, thanks to AgentP**`

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        var ctx = applicationContext
        setContent {
            val lifecycle: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
            checkExit(ctx, lifecycle)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun checkExit(ctx: Context, lifecycle: LifecycleOwner) {
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            when(event){
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP  -> {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "onExit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
        lifecycle.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            lifecycle.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I imagine it's not possible to do this through compose, maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682792/how-do-i-detect-if-the-user-has-left-my-app) can help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand the problem here you need to understand about [Side-Effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) in compose

What is **DisposableEffect**?

> A side effect of composition that must run for any new unique value of
> key1 and must be reversed or cleaned up if key1 changes or if the
> DisposableEffect leaves the composition.

Basically, It will run

1. when the key value you are passing to it changes or
2. when it leaves the composition.

In this case, it is happening for a second reason i.e it is causing due to its exit from composition

But why is it working when you back press and why not working when you kill app from recent?

To understand this in a better way read [onDispose callback not called when app is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541839/ondispose-callback-not-called-when-app-is-killed)

To quote from the answer to the above question

> Composer is `disposed` when `viewLifecycle` is in `ON_DESTROY` state. If
> `ON_DESTROY` is not dispatched, the composer will not dispose

So basically what happening is the composition will not dispose if it fails to receive the `ON_DESTORY` from the lifecycle

It's not safe to call anything in onDispose unless you are removing some observers and all.

How to fix this?

You can use below code

```
DisposableEffect(Unit) {
                    val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { lifecycleOwner, event ->
                         when(event){
                              Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP,Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY  -> {
                                  checkCtx()
                              }
                         }
                    }
                    lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
                    onDispose {
                         lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
                    }
               }
```

The obve code sets an observer for lifecycle events and calls the method `checkCtx()` when we lifecycle gets `ON_DESTROY` or `ON_STOP` as state

checkCtx() : Note its not a composable function it should reside in activity/fragment

```
private fun checkCtx() {
          Toast.makeText(this, "onExit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the full explanation and solution! Just one question, where does this "lifecycle" variable come from? (in lifecycle.addObserver(observer) )

Comment: it comes from Activity itself

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I got it and updated the question for those looking for the same in the future, have a nice day! :)

val lifecycle: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

Comment: there is a huge problem to this , there is no difference between recomposition and the composable actually quits the foreground , no difference as the composable is subject to recomposition many times and it still calls dispose while being in foreground

Comment: `Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY` is never triggered in `Compose` -  https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/compose/package-summary#LifecycleEventEffect(androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.Event,androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,kotlin.Function0)  - `This function should not be used to listen for Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY because Compose stops recomposing after receiving a Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP and will never be aware of an ON_DESTROY to launch onEvent.` And the answer got 8 votes...